# Nginx pointed to wrong directory with Docker on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I'm setting up a Laravel application with Docker, using a Docker image configuration I found here: https://blog.pusher.com/docker-for-development-laravel-php/

Now, this works fine on my Ubuntu machine (16.04), but on Window (10 Pro) I get a weird error. It first complains about not finding a `composer.json` file. Then, with each request I make to `localhost:8000`, I get the following error:

```
15#15: *1 open() "/var/www/public404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
```

I am very new to this, but it seems that nginx points to `/var/www/public404` - I have no idea how that "404" got there. I have a feeling it has to do with the line `try_files $uri = 404;` in the `site.conf` file, however, I don't really know how that works and I don't want to break it... The weird thing is that this works with Ubuntu, but not on Windows (or maybe that's not weird at all?).

I use `docker build . -t my-image` to build the image and `docker run -p 8000:80 --name="my-container" my-image` to run a container using the image.

The EOL of all the config files is set to line feed. Does anybody have any idea how I might fix this?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
LABEL maintainer="John Doe <john@doe>"

COPY start.sh /start.sh
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf

RUN apk add --update \
php7 \
php7-fpm \
php7-pdo \
php7-pdo_mysql \
php7-mcrypt \
php7-mbstring \
php7-xml \
php7-openssl \
php7-json \
php7-phar \
php7-zip \
php7-dom \
php7-session \
php7-tokenizer \
php7-zlib && \
php7 -r "copy('http://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
php7 composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer && \
php7 -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
ln -s /etc/php7/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/php.ini

RUN apk add --update \
bash \
openssh-client \
supervisor

RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx && \
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available && \
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled && \
mkdir -p /run/nginx && \
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf && \
mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor && \
rm -Rf /var/www/* && \
chmod 755 /start.sh

RUN sed -i -e "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g" \
-e "s/variables_order = \"GPCS\"/variables_order = \"EGPCS\"/g" \
/etc/php7/php.ini && \
sed -i -e "s/;daemonize\s*=\s*yes/daemonize = no/g" \
-e "s/;catch_workers_output\s*=\s*yes/catch_workers_output = yes/g" \
-e "s/user = nobody/user = nginx/g" \
-e "s/group = nobody/group = nginx/g" \
-e "s/;listen.mode = 0660/listen.mode = 0666/g" \
-e "s/;listen.owner = nobody/listen.owner = nginx/g" \
-e "s/;listen.group = nobody/listen.group = nginx/g" \
-e "s/listen = 127.0.0.1:9000/listen = \/var\/run\/php-fpm.sock/g" \
-e "s/^;clear_env = no$/clear_env = no/" \
/etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf

EXPOSE 443 80
WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the .env file if it does not exist.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

if [[ ! -f "/var/www/.env" ]] && [[ -f "/var/www/.env.example" ]];
then
cp /var/www/.env.example /var/www/.env
fi

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run Composer
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

if [[ ! -d "/var/www/vendor" ]];
then
cd /var/www
composer update
composer dump-autoload -o
fi

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start supervisord
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

exec /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

**site.conf**

```
server {
listen 80;

root /var/www/public;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ /\. {
deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri = 404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
access_log off;
sendfile on;
#tcp_nopush on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
#gzip on;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

**supervisord.conf**

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/dev/shm/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=warn
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
minfds=1024
minprocs=200
user=root

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///dev/shm/supervisor.sock

[program:php-fpm7]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=10
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Comment: You use docker toolbox or Docker for windows?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Docker for Windows. I have Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: What commands do you use to start the container itself? Do you run that command from powershell, git bash, cmd, or some other shell on your windows host?

Comment: @programmerq After reading your comment, I checked the source again and noticed that I didn't mount the volume... I added the `-v` parameter and it works. So stupid! I edited my posts to include the commands. If you post an answer to add the `-v` parameter, I can reward you the bounty!

Comment: in the site.conf try to putting `server_name localhost;` and  in location field replace this `try_files $uri = 404;` with this `try_files $uri /index.php =404;`

Comment: what's inside sites-enabled directory and what about content of default.conf?
also make sure that your whole laravel project is www directory not inside, if it's inside www so you should change root directory path.

Comment: @WouterC, please put the answer in the section below and mark this question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, I just forgot to add the `-v` parameter in the `docker run` command, like so:

```
docker run -p 8000:80 -v $PWD/src:/var/www --name="my-container" my-image
```

... with `$PWD/src` being the full path to the `src` directory.